# Small hint for making query in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb

how can i make a query for my practice.I have two tables, one is football clubs and other is players. football clubs have next atributes: (id, name,stadium,president, founding year) and players(id,club_id,name,surname,date of birth,position) so i want to make query to show me all the clubs and players that are founded after 1902 for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name,
       p.surname, p.name, p.position
FROM Clubs AS c
JOIN Players AS p  ON p.club_id = c.id
WHERE c.founding_year = 1902;
```